# Android AAR NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, aar

I am attempting to open source [a library](https://github.com/BrantApps/Polaris) that I have created but encountering problems with the generated AAR and `NoClassDefFoundError`s when I attempt to use the library under a Gradle built APK. Notably, if I convert the AAR to the older, unofficial and now deprecated `apklib` format (and use under a `android-maven-plugin` built APK) the library works without issue.

With this evidence I'm likely seeing an android-gradle-plugin deficiency. From attempting all of the [documented](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=55863) [roots](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips#TOC-Handling-transitive-dependencies-for-local-artifacts-jars-and-aar-) including relying on a local maven repo including the AARs and importing the AARs using Studio's module import mechanism the error remains.

Deeper investigation indicates that not all the library's classes suffer the issue noted below. Specifically, there are problems with those classes that themselves rely on Google Play Services or the Android Support Library. A similar issue (probably exactly the same, in fact) was noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357692/noclassdeffounderror-at-runtime-on-class-inside-aar-in-android-studio) back in February.

The exception I am seeing is below;

```
04-21 00:02:25.863  21336-21336/com.oceanlife E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.oceanlife, PID: 21336
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.brantapps.polaris.google.GoogleMapWrapper
            at com.brantapps.polaris.PolarisModule.provideMappable(PolarisModule.java:46)
            at com.brantapps.polaris.PolarisModule$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideMappableProvidesAdapter.get(PolarisModule$$ModuleAdapter.java:57)
            at com.brantapps.polaris.PolarisModule$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideMappableProvidesAdapter.get(PolarisModule$$ModuleAdapter.java:41)
            at com.oceanlife.fragment.addspot.AddSpotMapFragment.onCreate(AddSpotMapFragment.java:171)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

The project's configuration can be viewed under the [GitHub repo here](https://github.com/BrantApps/Polaris) but here are the build dependencies I have for clarity;

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'

    googleCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'

    kindleCompile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.1'
    kindleCompile 'org.osmdroid:osmbonuspack:4.4'
    kindleCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.7'

    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.+'
}
```

Any insight/workarounds to this issue graciously received.

Comment: I've worked around this by placing the AAR code under a flavour. Will retry with the next release of the build tooling.

Comment: Still doesn't work as I seem to expect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that if I repeat the dependencies that are causing the `NoDefFoundError` (as described in the linked SO) within the main application then the issue goes away...

It seems that the library AARs are built without the *Google Play* and *Support Library* dependencies. I believe I can build it correctly and force the dependencies to be resolved by generating an appropriate `pom.xml` that sits alongside the AAR in my local maven repo.

For reference here is my project configuration;

Android Studio:

```
--App
  -- build.gradle (repeat dependencies of Polaris)
--Polaris
  -- build.gradle (Google Play and Support dependencies)
--ApiClient
  -- build.gradle (just another module)
```

Local Maven:

```
--.m2
  -- com
    -- brantapps
      -- polaris-google
        -- 1.0.0
          -- polaris-google-1.0.0.aar
          -- polaris-google-1.0.0.pom (need to build one of these maybe!)
```